# Axios expose response headers: Content-Disposition

Tags: cors, axios, content-disposition, response-headers

I was able to set request headers to expose Content-Disposition by adding:
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Disposition"

I can see the response but the response object does not include Content-Disposition.
[image: headers]

Is there any way i can access that value?

axios version: 0.15.2
Environment: node v6.9.4, chrome 54, windows 7

Comment: Hi am facing the same issue. Did you find a soulution for this.?

Comment: Hi i got the same issue, any finding?

Answer (score 56):

In my case I had to enable CORS-related feature on the server side:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
```

This allows javascript on the browser side to read this header.
In case of node.js + express + cors on the server side it may looks like this:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition']
}))
```

So I can see "content-disposition" among the headers, returned by Axios.

Comment: I am using a django backend with a vue frontend, and setting the header in the django side fixed it for me too.